# getCurrentPosition is not getting called ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, geolocation, currentlocation

I am trying to build an app where I need to get the user's current position.
So I was trying to use

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition, showError);
}
```

This if condition is called. But after this, neither `showPosition` nor `showError` function is called. My `showPosition` function is

```
function showPosition(position) {alert('success');}
```

and my `showError` function is

```
function showError(error) {alert('error');}
```

I am developing the app by using ReactJS, as browser I am using Chrome(the latest version).
It would be very helpful is anyone help me with this.

Comment: Provide your react code here. What did you attempt as a react code?

Comment: Do you get an error somewhere or is just nothing happening? Have you tried `if (!navigator.geolocation) {alert('Location not accessible')}` to see if you actually can access the location?

Comment: I am trying to get the user's current location.

Comment: works for me Do you authorized chrome to get the position [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-fermat-si770)

Comment: @consager nothing happening actually....

Comment: @antoineso after running your sandbox I am getting like this https://ibb.co/mRQvc97

Comment: @SaddafAfrin That's not an error. That's what your browser asking you to allow your location information. Just allow it. You will see the data.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution:

[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-nyuuow?file=src%2FApp.js)

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";

const App = props => {
  useEffect(() => {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition, showError);
    }
  }, []);

  const showPosition = data => {
    console.log("position");
    console.log(position);
  };

  const showError = err => {
    console.log("err");
    console.log(err.message);
  };

  return <div>Hello, open the console to see the result</div>;
};

export default App;
```

Comment: @SaddafAfrin That's not an error. That's what your browser asking you to allow your location information. Just allow it. You will see the data.

Comment: Well I did allow the location But still got this... https://ibb.co/gRvY4Qm

Comment: Can you try this in your code instead of testing here?

Comment: For testing you can run this code directly in you browser console `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((data) => console.log('data', data), (ee) => console.log('err', err));`

Comment: I am not saying the pop up is the error... I was trying to show you that I have allowed the location. And after trying my code i am getting this https://ibb.co/F8S1PJ6

Comment: Can you replace the err to err.message? `console.log(err.message);` to check the exact error message? If it is saying that "it is disabled by feature policy" then try in your code instead of playing within stackblitz.

Comment: I am getting "Geolocation has been disabled in this document by permissions policy." How can I enable this? https://ibb.co/LdXwKWB

Comment: I have found the problem... Thank you so much for the help...

Comment: Pleasure, Can you upvote please if it helped you?